# Javascript Onclick two events

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am looking for a unique solution for my issue. I am looking to submit 2 events with 1 onclick. The majority of answers involve creating a `function()` but part of my function involves using a PHP loop.

Currently this code only executes the second event. Conversely if I switch the events the other event will occur. Basically whichever event is last will execute.

```
if($result){
    if(mysql_affected_rows() != 0){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
              
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr style='cursor: pointer' onclick=\"document.location = 'test.php?airport_id=" . $row['id'] . "'; document['myform'].submit(); return false; \";>";
    echo "<td width=100 align=left><font color=#FFFFFF>" . $row['ident'] . "</font></td>";
```

What do you suggest as a solution?

Comment: You can't submit a form *and* change the location .. when your form gets submitted, why don't you just redirect on the PHP side?

Comment: The change location is for my live search function. http://fpmnky.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever think to use AJAX?
You could submit your form through AJAX. After submission is Okay, trigger your redirect function; This link might help you: http://www.jstiles.com/Blog/How-To-Submit-a-Form-with-jQuery-and-AJAX